# fetch realm data based on dynamic type

Tags: android, realm, realm-list

I have created following classes in realm for entities like employee , Student and storing its sync status in SyscInfo class

```
Employee extends RealmObject      
  _id
  name
  phone
  address
  isSync

Student extends RealmObject      
 _id
 name
 phone
 isSync


SyncInfo extends RealmObject      
  isSync
  timestamp
```

Now if any emploee or student records are not synced i am setting `syncInfo.isSync` to `false`

my background scheduler will check whether we have any offline / not synced data stored in realm db. for that i am firing query for  employee and student both.

```
    RealmList<Employee> offlineEmployeeList = realm.where(Employee.class).equalTo("syncInfo.isSync",false).findAllAsync();
    RealmList<Student> offlineEmployeeList = realm.where(Student.class).equalTo("syncInfo.isSync",false).findAllAsync();
```

so what i am looking is , do we have any generalized way to check offline / unsynced data without checking into each entity i.e. Employee and Student.
tomorrow if one more entity got introduced , i again have to fire the same query.

Comment: If you want to treat `Employee` and `Student` the same, then they should be the same class: `Person`. And employee/student should be `type` of Person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create this generic method:

```
private <T extends RealmModel> RealmResults<T> getNotSynced(Class<T> modelClass) {
    return realm.where(modelClass).equalTo("isSynced", false).findAll();
}
```

And use it like this:

```
Set<Class<? extends RealmModel>> realmObjectClasses = realm.getConfiguration().getRealmObjectClasses();

ArrayList<RealmResults> notSynched = new ArrayList<>();
for(Class modelClass: realmObjectClasses) {
  notSynched.add(getNotSynced(schemaClasses));
}

// Now you have an array of RealmResults with non-synched RealmObjects
```

About the query method,

I would use the `findAll()` method and execute the hole thing on a background thread, and **not** the `findAllAsync()`, the later requires a more complex synchronisation as I see it.

**UPDATE**

If not all RealmObjects has the `isSynced` field, here is what I would do:

RealmObjects has some limitations, but you can implement an empty interface, so I would use that to identify syncable objects and use the `getNotSynced` method only on them:

Create an empty interface:

```
public interface Syncable {}
```

Implement it with all the syncable RealmObjects:

```
Employee extends RealmObject implements Syncable {
  ...
}
```

And then use it to filter the classes in the for loop from before:

```
for(Class modelClass: realmObjectClasses) {
  if (Syncable.class.isAssignableFrom(modelClass)) {
    notSynched.add(getNotSynced(schemaClasses));
  }
}
```

Comment: this is fine but again the problem is same , i got to call this for each entity. `getNotSynced(Contact.class)` for all other entities

Comment: I see.. Edited my answer.

Comment: I have used your approach by handling exception `Invalid query: field 'syncInfo' not found in class 'XXX` as not all realm class has this field

Comment: Cool.. that's one way to do it, I can suggest another way if you want. I have a question though.. the field name is `isSync`, why are you using `syncInfo`? Isn't that the name of one of the RealmObjects?

Comment: Yes please suggest , ah I changed the field name but purpose is same

Comment: What's the other way

Comment: Sorry I was busy, posted it :)

Comment: Ahh that's nice , this will narrow down the lookups n no need to check for invalid query .. thanks :)

Comment: Glad you liked it :) happy coding!

Comment: Share ur online id just to share knowledge sometimes :)

Comment: I tried your code with ` if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(ISync.class))` where `ISync` is the interface implemented by the classes having `SyncInfo` but it never falls under this condition

Comment: Oops.. I think I got it backwards.. It should be  if(Syncable.class.isAssignableFrom(modelClass)). Edited. Sorry :)

Comment: Yeah just found out :)